# for loop printing only last item in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

Guys i am in a trouble here. I made a table of songs, then i inserted them in local storage, and now i want to search the items in local storage to see if a name of an album exists in local storage(in a table) or not, i made this .js code and when i try to search for items in local storage(objects in array), for example i try searching for california and it prints "NO" but there is one in local storage called california, but when i search for chuck it prints "YES", and if i add one more it will do the same, it will print only the last item in this array, why is this happening. Thanks in advance.

```js
let ls = [{
    name: "california",
    artist: "blink182",
    year: 2016,
    num: 28
  },
  {
    name: "chuck",
    artist: "sum41",
    year: 2004,
    num: 13
  }
];

localStorage.setItem("songs", JSON.stringify(ls));

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", search);

function search(e) {
  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("songs"));
  let inputVal = document.getElementById("input").value;
  let outputVal = document.getElementById("output");



  for (let i = 0; i < ls.length; i++) {
    if (inputVal === ls[i].name) {
      outputVal.innerHTML = "YES";
    } else {
      outputVal.innerHTML = "NO";
    }
  }

  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lime;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}

div {
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name of album</th>
    <th>Artist</th>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>numOfTracks</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>California</td>
    <td>Blink 182</td>
    <td>2016</td>
    <td>28</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Chuck</td>
    <td>Sum 41</td>
    <td>2004</td>
    <td>13</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<form id="myForm">
  <p>Search LS</p>
  <input type="text" id="input">
  <button type="submit" id="btn">Search</button>
</form>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: You need to end the loop when you found something.

Comment: Also, you aren't assigning `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("songs"))` to anything, so why do that at all?

Answer (score 0):

The  problem is that you're setting the `HTML` of the div to YES/NO. Which is being overridden in the next iteration that's why you feel like it's printing for the last item in the list. Instead you need to append to what's already there

```
  for (let i = 0; i < ls.length; i++) {
    if (inputVal === ls[i].name) {
      outputVal.innerHTML = outputVal.innerHTML + " YES" ;
    } else {
      outputVal.innerHTML = outputVal.innerHTML + " NO";
    }
  }
```

Now you should be able to see `YESNO` for the list values

Answer (score 0):

```js
function search(e) {
  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("songs"));
  let inputVal = document.getElementById("input").value;
  let outputVal = document.getElementById("output");

  var resultExists = false;
  var resultCount  = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < ls.length; i++) {
    if (inputVal === ls[i].name) {
      // Case 2
      resultExists = true;
      resultCount++;
      
      // Updated your case
      // outputVal.innerHTML = "YES";
      // break;
      
    } 
    //else {
    //  outputVal.innerHTML = "NO";
    //}
  }
  
  // Case 2
  if(resultExists){
    outputVal.innerHTML = "YES";
    // Do anithing with resultCount if you need
  }else{
    outputVal.innerHTML = "NO";
  }

  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
function search(e) {
  let songs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("songs"));
  let inputVal = document.getElementById("input").value;
  let outputVal = document.getElementById("output");

  outputVal.innerHTML = dataContainsField(ls, inputVal) ? "YES" : "NO";

  e.preventDefault();
}

function dataContainsField(data, field) {
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (field === data[i].name) return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Putting the logic to check for the existence of the data in your dataset into a function makes it easier to code and decouples that logic from your search function.

Answer (score 0):

It's printing all the items but you are overwriting the innerHTML value each time instead of adding to it, see the edit below.

```js
let ls = [{
        name: "california",
        artist: "blink182",
        year: 2016,
        num: 28
      },
      {
        name: "chuck",
        artist: "sum41",
        year: 2004,
        num: 13
      }
    ];

    // localStorage.setItem("songs", JSON.stringify(ls));

    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", search);

    function search(e) {
      // JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("songs"));
      let inputVal = document.getElementById("input").value;
      let outputVal = document.getElementById("output");
      /* note the use of += instead of = */
      for (let i = 0; i < ls.length; i++) {
        if (inputVal === ls[i].name) {
          outputVal.innerHTML += "YES";
        } else {
          outputVal.innerHTML += "NO";
        }
      }

      e.preventDefault();
    }
```

```css
body {
      background-color: lime;
      line-height: 1.5;
      font-size: 15px;
      margin: auto;
      width: 80%;
    }

    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 2px solid black;
      padding: 20px;
    }

    div {
      margin: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name of album</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>numOfTracks</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>California</td>
        <td>Blink 182</td>
        <td>2016</td>
        <td>28</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Chuck</td>
        <td>Sum 41</td>
        <td>2004</td>
        <td>13</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <form id="myForm">
      <p>Search LS</p>
      <input type="text" id="input">
      <button type="submit" id="btn">Search</button>
    </form>

    <div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: (ps: you'll need to outputVal.innerHTML = ' '; before the loop to clear the previous result and consider setting the case on the text for matching)

Answer (score 0):

As you're using `for` loop that's why every time it is just **overwriting** you value with last value. You can try like this with [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). Also you've some issue with your **localStorage** data parsing inside your `search(e)` function, here you're not storing it to `ls` variable before doing any find/search operation

**See working demo** https://jsfiddle.net/ttr80ona/

```
let ls = [{name: "california",artist: "blink182",year: 2016,num: 28},{name: "chuck",artist: "sum41",year: 2004,num: 13}];

localStorage.setItem("songs", JSON.stringify(ls));

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", search);

function search(e) {
  let ls = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("songs")); //I've modified here
  let inputVal = document.getElementById("input").value;
  let outputVal = document.getElementById("output");

  var status = ls.find(elm => elm.name === inputVal);
  if (status)
    outputVal.innerHTML = "YES";
  else
    outputVal.innerHTML = "NO";

  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are overriding yes with no. You should set default to false and make it true once found or remove else condition.

```
function search(e) {
  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("songs"));
  let inputVal = document.getElementById("input").value;
  let outputVal = document.getElementById("output");
  let bFound = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < ls.length; i++) {
    if(inputVal === ls[i].name) {
      bFound = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  outputVal.innerHTML = bFound ? "YES" : "No";
  e.preventDefault();
}
```